# Automatically record daily values in a new column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

So I have this spreadsheet I use to control Content funnel.
I've come up with a few formulas to use something else than a pivot table.
But in order to get the trends and alarms I'm looking for, I need to start recording this data daily.. automatically.
This is the spreadsheet:

[image]

I'm looking for a script that would add a column between columns B and C, setting current date in cell C1, and completing each cell below with the corresponding value to each formula in each cell.

Here's the list of forumlas I'm using:

```
C2: =counta(Check!$J:$J)
C3: =COUNTIF(Check!$L:$L,Validation!$A$6)
C4: =COUNTIF(Check!$L:$L,Validation!$A$7)
C5: =ARRAYFORMULA(countif(Check!$L:$L&Check!$O:$O,Validation!$A$5&"") )
C6: =countif(Check!$O:$O,Validation!$A$1)
C7: =ARRAYFORMULA(countif(Check!L:L&Check!O:O,Validation!A5&Validation!A2) )
C8: =ARRAYFORMULA(countif(Check!O:O&Check!Q:Q,Validation!A1&"") )
C9: =countif(Check!Q:Q,Validation!A1)
C10: =countif(Check!Q:Q,Validation!A2)
C11: =countif(Check!T:T,Validation!A1)
```

So far I've only achieved this much:

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Approval Funnel");
  var source = sheet.getRange("C2:C11");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.insertColumns(3);
```

And that's the frontier of my coding knowledge.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draft is pretty good, but there is a design flaw: if you insert the values between B and C, then the column with formulas will become D. So, next time the script will try to get data, it will be looking at a wrong place.

Simply put, the *source* of the data you are recording (i.e., the column with formulas) should stay in the same place. You can put the historical data to the right of it.  Like this:

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Approval Funnel");
  var source = sheet.getRange("C2:C11");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values = [[new Date()]].concat(values);    // prepending the date to values
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(3);                // inserting AFTER column C
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();         
  sheet.getRange("D1:D11").setValues(values);
}
```

I put `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` to make sure that the previous changes (namely, inserting a column) is indeed made before the script puts the data in with `setValues`.

Also you had an error in `values[0][0] = new Date();` -- this command would overwrite the 0th element of array (namely, the content of C2) with the date. You wanted to prepend the date, which is what I did by creating a new array with one element, `[[new Date()]]`, and concatenating values to it.

Comment: It worked, Norma!
You made it look so easy. Thanks!