# Automatically record daily values from a column in a new row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-apps-script

I currently have a project tracker in a Google sheet which records a project name, status character column and three progress columns as below:

[image]

I would like to record a daily log of each progress relative to the project so that I have a table recording the following headings automatically:
Date,   Project 1 Progress 1,   Project 1 Progress 2,   Project 1 Progress 3,   Project 2 Progress 1,   Project 2 Progress 2,   etc...

I have been able to use the following script to copy one columns daily data to another column, but don't know how to transpose this:

```
  function recordHistory() {var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source = sheet.getRange("C2:C8");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values = [[new Date()]].concat(values);    // prepending the date to values
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(7);                // inserting AFTER column G
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();         
  sheet.getRange("G1:G8").setValues(values)
```

Which I modified from this post: ([Automatically record daily values in a new column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88937/automatically-record-daily-values-in-a-new-column)).

Ideally, I would like to be able to visualize the progress in a graph as well as get some basic stats around how fast we are completing given projects so I can better predict future projects time to completion. I am honestly at a loss and have only just begun working with macros in Google Sheets, so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated, as I'm trying to do this without using R or similar software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> don't know how to transpose this

You are already recording the progress daily using a script function. To make the function copy data into a blank column instead of overwriting previously recorded data, replace `.insertColumnAfter(7)` with `.insertColumnAfter(6)`. To run the script once a day, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

To transpose the data into a new sheet, **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `G1` of the new sheet:

`=query( transpose(Sheet1!F1:K), "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0 )`

...where `F` is one column before the first column with recorded data and `K` is the current last column with recorded data. The formula will automatically adjust and expand its range as new columns are inserted daily.

Then **Insert > Chart** whose data range points to the transposed data on the new sheet. You can place the chart in the project data sheet if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy help @doubleunary! If I wanted to transpose in the same sheet is there a way to do it so that my current script generates rows instead of columns?

Comment: That can be done, but I am afraid you would be in trouble with that in the longer run. Use the solution above to minimize hassle down the road. Note that you can place the _chart_ in the project data sheet even when the chart's data range is in the transposed record sheet. Or you can create a chart directly from the record data without transposing.